# TOAST UI Image Editor addIcon icon size

Tags: toast-ui-image-editor, toast-ui-editor

I am using the TOAST UI Image Editor to add custom SVG icons to my image:

```
imageEditor.addIcon(iconType, {
    left: originPointer.x,
    top: originPointer.y,
    fill: iconColor
});
```

Is it possible to also set the size of the icon? I tried

```
imageEditor.setObjectPropertiesQuietly(object.id, {
    width: 100,
    height: 100
});
```

but had no luck as this only seems to affect the bounding box of the icon but not the icon size itself. Thank you very much in advance.